C++: MySQL xdevapi crashes when inserting data (throws no meta-data found error)
I'm trying to insert some data in a MySQL table using the C++ Xdevapi. The following code for inserting something in a table unsurprisingly works:
t.insert().values(0, "cng", "CNG").execute();            // Works as expected
t.insert("code", "name").values("cng", "CNG").execute(); // Also works

However, I can't use this option as I do not know the amount of columns and fields at compile time. As Xdevapi's documentation is lacking to say the least I've had to resort to a lot of experimentation. The most logical attempt I tried was the following code which uses a Row instead:
mysqlx::abi2::Row row1;

row1.set(1, 0);
row1.set(2, "cng");
row1.set(3, "CNG");

// t.insert().values(row1).execute(); // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
                                      //   what():  no meta-data found

// t.insert().rows(row1).execute();   // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
                                      //   what():  no meta-data found

But this code fails due to a "no meta-data found" exception.
For the record, the following code (which defeats the purpose by having to specify the column names which I don't know at compile time) also fails with the same exception:
mysqlx::abi2::Row row2;

row2.set(1, "cng");
row2.set(2, "CNG");

// t.insert("code", "name").values(row2).execute(); // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
                                                    //   what():  no meta-data found
                                                   
// t.insert("code", "name").rows(row2).execute();   // terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
                                                    //   what():  no meta-data found

I know I can solve the issue by writing my own SQL queries using Session.sql(), but surely there must be a better solution? Is there any way I can specify the meta-data it doesn't find?

The documentation for this Row class says fields are 0-based, not 1-based...

Tried that too, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be right as it then thinks "cng" is my ID instead of Code:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mysqlx::abi2::r0::Error'
what():  CDK Error: Incorrect integer value: 'cng' for column 'id' at row 1
